# How to Test a Class Method in Rspec that has a Has Many Through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

How would I test the class method .trending in Rspec considering that it has a has many through association. .trending works but it currently has not been properly vetted in Rspec. Any advice?

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts

  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :name_length

  def self.trending
    hash = {}
    all.each{|x|
      hash[x.id] = x.comments.where("comments.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now - 7.days).count
    }
    new_hash = hash.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse!.to_h
    new_hash.delete_if {|k, v| v < 1 } 
    new_hash.map do |k,v,|
        self.find(k)      
    end
  end

  private

  def name_length
    unless name.nil?

      if name.length < 2
        errors.add(:name, 'must be longer than 1 character')
      end

    end
  end

end
```

Test I attempted to use (it didn't work)

```
  describe ".trending" do
    it "an instance of Author should be able to return trending" do
      @author = FactoryGirl.build(:author, name:'drew', created_at: Time.now - 11.years, id: 1)
      @post = @author.posts.build(id: 1, body:'hello', subject:'hello agains', created_at: Time.now - 10.years)
      @comment1 = @post.comments.build(id: 1, body: 'this is the body', created_at: Time.now - 9.years)
      @comment2 = @post.comments.build(id: 2, body: 'this was the body', created_at: Time.now - 8.years)
      @comment3 = @post.comments.build(id: 3, body: 'this shall be the body', created_at: Time.now - 7.minutes)
      Author.trending.should include(@comment3)
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, I'm a bit confused, why is the trending scope doing a bunch of work in Ruby? Can't you just define the scope to be what you want?

Comment: Thats some pretty scary code, you have a serious n+1 query issue...

Answer (score 0):

Neither `FactoryGirl.build` nor `ActiveRecord::Relation#build` persists a record to the database—they just return an un-saved instance of the object—but `Author.trending` is looking for records in the database. You should either call `save` on the instances to persist them to the database, or use `create` instead of `build`.